# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.nsia.officems.OfficemsApplication]

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, intellij-idea

I have a Spring-boot rest API Project when I want to run it as debug mode or run it directly from IntelliJ it gives me the above error and when I run it from the terminal and use **mvn spring-boot:run** and use this command it works for me and runs the project successfully, I need to debug my project and need it to run as debug mode,
can anyone help me??

Comment: Can you please share class com.nsia.officems.OfficemsApplication?

Comment: Thanks for your Reply dear @RohitAgarwal I solved my problems by following these steps in Intellij  File->Invalidate Cashes->Tick All Options>Invalidate and Restart